# How to disable global remapping effect in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make the `Shift` key behave like `PageDown`, then I write a script

```
~Shift::
    KeyWait, Shift
    Send, {PgDn}
```

However, when I want to type 'A', I pressed the key `Shift` and the key `a`, `PageDown` was triggered.

How to disable `PageDown` effect when I want to type 'A'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Shift:: Send {PgDn}
```

The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the Send command from triggering it.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Comment: user3419297, dependence on computers/system, need level a keyboard, try add `#InputLevel 1` and look a example https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm